# Подскажите пожалуйста,можно ли оптимизировать код?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

```
let p1 = document.querySelector('.p1');
p1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(document.querySelector('.d1').style.display != 'block')
    {
        document.querySelector('.d1').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.querySelector('.d1').style.display = 'none';
    }
});


let p2 = document.querySelector('.p2');
p2.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(document.querySelector('.d2').style.display != 'block')
    {
        document.querySelector('.d2').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.querySelector('.d2').style.display = 'none';
    }
});



let p3 = document.querySelector('.p3');
p3.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(document.querySelector('.d3').style.display != 'block')
    {
        document.querySelector('.d3').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.querySelector('.d3').style.display = 'none';
    }
});



let p4 = document.querySelector('.p4');
p4.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(document.querySelector('.d4').style.display != 'block')
    {
        document.querySelector('.d4').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.querySelector('.d4').style.display = 'none';
    }
});

let p5 = document.querySelector('.p5');
p5.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(document.querySelector('.d5').style.display != 'block')
    {
        document.querySelector('.d5').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.querySelector('.d5').style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Пункт 1 можно пропустить - перейти сразу к пункту 2.</sub>

---

1. Для начала можно чуть-чуть лишние пробелы убрать - легче читать будет:

```js
let p1 = document.querySelector('.p1');
p1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (document.querySelector('.d1').style.display != 'block') {
        document.querySelector('.d1').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('.d1').style.display = 'none';
    }
});

let p2 = document.querySelector('.p2');
p2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (document.querySelector('.d2').style.display != 'block') {
        document.querySelector('.d2').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('.d2').style.display = 'none';
    }
});

let p3 = document.querySelector('.p3');
p3.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (document.querySelector('.d3').style.display != 'block') {
        document.querySelector('.d3').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('.d3').style.display = 'none';
    }
});

let p4 = document.querySelector('.p4');
p4.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (document.querySelector('.d4').style.display != 'block') {
        document.querySelector('.d4').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('.d4').style.display = 'none';
    }
});

let p5 = document.querySelector('.p5');
p5.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (document.querySelector('.d5').style.display != 'block') {
        document.querySelector('.d5').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('.d5').style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```html
<p class="p1">p1</p>
<p class="p2">p2</p>
<p class="p3">p3</p>
<p class="p4">p4</p>
<p class="p5">p5</p>

<div class="d1">d1</div>
<div class="d2">d2</div>
<div class="d3">d3</div>
<div class="d4">d4</div>
<div class="d5">d5</div>
```

2. Когда стало легче читать, объединяем в цикл повторяющиеся блоки:

```js
let p = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  p[i] = document.querySelector('.p' + i);
  p[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (document.querySelector('.d' + i).style.display != 'block') {
      document.querySelector('.d' + i).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.querySelector('.d' + i).style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<p class="p1">p1</p>
<p class="p2">p2</p>
<p class="p3">p3</p>
<p class="p4">p4</p>
<p class="p5">p5</p>

<div class="d1">d1</div>
<div class="d2">d2</div>
<div class="d3">d3</div>
<div class="d4">d4</div>
<div class="d5">d5</div>
```

Comment: Перед тем как ответить, код хотя бы проверь

Comment: А тут не работает

Comment: действует со второго клика...

Comment: Я бы еще `document.querySelector('.d' + i).style.display` в `let elmStyle = document.querySelector('.d' + i).style.display` переделал.

Answer (score 6):

Конечно можно...

Что бы не прописывать, отдельно функцию для каждого элемента, лучше использовать циклы.

Именно данный пример реализован методом `forEach((s, i arr )=>{})`

У которого есть три аргумента  ***`s - это аналог this, i - это индекс элемента и arr - это коллекция`***, ***последний в данном примере не нужен***.

```js
const d = document.querySelectorAll('.d');

// прокручиваем все эллементы в цикле
[...document.querySelectorAll('.p')].forEach((s, i) => {
// S - это тот элемент на который кликнули
  s.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // [i] - это индекс того элемента на который  кликнули
  // идалее тернаный оператор в аналог if(){}
  // если у данного элемента d[i].style.display === 'none'то 
  // присваиваем block или на оборот
    d[i].style.display = (d[i].style.display === 'none') ?
      d[i].style.display = 'block' :
      d[i].style.display = 'none'
  })
})
```

```html
<p class="p p1">p1</p>
<p class="p p2">p2</p>
<p class="p p3">p3</p>
<p class="p p4">p4</p>

<div class="d d1">d1</div>
<div class="d d2">d2</div>
<div class="d d3">d3</div>
<div class="d d4">d4</div>
```

Но как справедливо отметил, Grundy, в комментах, то если изменить структуру верстки, данный пример не будет работать верно, так как будет нарушена последовательность элементов. Если элементы в верстке расположены не подряд, 
но надо что бы тот или иной конкретный элемент имел воздействие на тот или иной, то придется код исправлять для реализации конкретной задачи

Comment: в чем заключается оптимизация?

Comment: если поменяешь в разметке местами p1 и p2 - код станет неверно работать

Comment: @Grundy, как минимум то, что он короче... Я в курсе что перестанет, но я отвечал исходя от из того, что есть ...

Comment: В том, что есть, код не зависит от положения элементов в разметке.

Comment: @Grundy, если бы я видел разметку, я может быть реализовал по другому...

Comment: Air, всё, работает!

Comment: Рад был помочь...

Comment: Осталось,разобраться в вашем коде))я недавно начал js учить

Comment: минут через 30 напишу пояснения...

Comment: было-бы круто!!

Comment: Глянь ответ....

Comment: ))))спасибо,буду разбираться и учить дальше!

Comment: Удачи........)))

Comment: @Air Хороший ответ (+) и главное есть поясняющие комментарии, которые помогают новичкам в `JS` понять код

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, благодарю...